# Submit button on Comments

Tags: php, drupal-8

I need to change the text on the "Save" button on the comments to "Post".  This is in Drupal 8.  How do you change that?  It seems pretty simple but it appears to be a php solution, which I am not good at.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) in your .theme file. It'll be something like:

```
if (isset($form['actions']['publish'])) {
  $form['actions']['publish']['#value'] = t('Post');
}
```